# How to get url of next page of clicking submit button in Protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am able to run the test code and i am able to submit the form. I need the url of next page when submit button is click. I need to get url of next page when submit button is clicked. But i am getting curenturl of first page. 
My code:

```
describe('Pmts app 5.0',function(){
var LoginPage = require("./LoginPO");
it('login test', function(){
LoginPage.setUserName('xyz@test.com');
LoginPage.setPassWord('test');
LoginPage.clickButton();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://localhost:1234/#/timesheet');
});
});
```

After submit button is clicked browser get closed immediately and it is not waiting for next page to load. Once the button is submitted it should wait until next page load and I need url of next page...

Answer (score 3):

Put it in the following way:

```
LoginPage.clickButton().then(function(){ expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://localhost:1234/#/timesheet');
})
```

or you can put a explicit hard sleep:

```
browser.sleep(time in ms)
```

or you can put a browser.wait() to wait for certain element that appears on the next page:

```
        browser.wait(function(){
           return elem.isPresent()
        },time in ms).then(function(){     
     expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
.toEqual('https://localhost:1234/#/timesheet');
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refrain from using *browser.sleep(number)*, instead go for *browser.waitForAngular()* if your application is Angular.js based.

Using hard coded dependency is never a good idea.

I have noticed, that the time Protractor needs to load the whole page varies. Therefore, either use *browser.waitForAngular()* or set a high number in *browser.sleep()*

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
describe('Pmts app 5.0',function(){
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    var LoginPage = require("./LoginPO");

    it('login test', function(){
        LoginPage.setUserName('xyz@test.com');
        LoginPage.setPassWord('test');
        LoginPage.clickButton();
        ptor.sleep(1000); 
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://localhost:1234/#/timesheet');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution but When I use "ptor = protractor.getInstance();" in my code it show error :" TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Try this:   var ptor = browser;

Comment: Putting in sleep values presupposes that the value will always be correct.  It's not possible to always assume some sleep value is correct.  e.g. This same test is used for load testing of 1,000,000 users...  Always use a wait on condition as it's the same thing an an event telling you when the next step is ready to go.